# Magento 2: set Tier price programmatically face issue of unchecked default store view

Tags: magento2, store-view, tierprice

> Before I set in admin like below

[image]

> After I execute script to update tier price for same product  it changes as like below which is issue

[image]

Code I use to set tier price is below

```
    $tierPrices[] = [
        'cust_group' => 17,
        'price' => 16.57,
        'website_id' => 0,
        'price_qty' => 5,
   ];
  $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku, ['edit_mode' => true]);
  $product->setData('tier_price', $tierPrices);
  $this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Comment: I think you need to run the script with a set store id and check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this was magento bug which is resolved in 2.4.2+

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26484